# Access 2007 Search Button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having trouble trying to get this to work for me, I have a inputbox to locate an account number in my table, but i want it to continue to keep locating that account number as my table with have more than one line with the same account number. This is what i currently have but I cant figure out how to do a find next record with the same account number.

```
Dim strAccount As String
Dim rstQA As Recordset

strAccount = InputBox("Enter Account Number")

If strAccount = "" Then Exit Sub
Set rstQA = Me.Recordset.Clone
rstQA.FindFirst "[Account Number]='" & strAccount & "'"
If rstQA.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No record of account"
Else
Me.Bookmark = rstQA.Bookmark
End If

rstQA.Close
Set rstQA = Nothing
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the subsequent matches? I think you can only bookmark one record so you'll need to do something else with the remaining matches.

Comment: Might be better to Filter the recordset on the Account Number.

Comment: Would it be better if I used another form to search the the table and populate the information I want on the other form?

Comment: What is your reluctance to use filter? Does my answer below not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I actually went a completely different route. I used another form along with a sub-form and did a filter search in the sub-form of the table, giving the user an option to select the line in which the account number is associated with. Thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to display the matching accounts in the form your best option is probably to filter the form:

```
Dim strAccount As String

strAccount = InputBox("Enter Account Number")

If strAccount = "" Then Exit Sub
Me.Filter  "[Account Number]='" & strAccount & "'"
Me.FilterOn = -1
```

To return to unfiltered code a separate button:

```
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = 0
```

Don't forget to put your Search and Unfilter buttons in either the header or footer of the form, otherwise if you filter returns no records you'll have a blank form.